# How to set Z-order of a Control using WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, focus, z-order

I'm writing a custom `TextBox` that upon gaining focus changes its border style.

As adding a border causes the control to overlap with those neighbouring it, I temporarily bring the text box to the front of the dialog (using `textBox.BringToFront()`).

However, once editing is complete and focus is lost, I would like to send the control back to its original position in the Z-order.

Is this possible (preferably in a simple way!)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Call the [`GetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh.aspx) and [`SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) methods of the parent's `Controls` collection.

Comment: Great - Led astray by BringToFront() I looked in the wrong place for these methods: at the control's methods, not the parent's controls' methods. Thanks.

Comment: No need example, the answer it self it's enough!

Comment: From reference: "The control with an index value of zero is at the top of the z-order, and higher numbers are closer to the bottom."

Comment: Interestingly enough, BringToFront() relies on SetChildIndex() if the control's parent is not null

Answer (score 31):

There is no Z-order as there was in VB, but you can use the [`GetChildIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SetChildIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to get and set their indexes manually.

[Here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/change-control-stacking-order-in-c/) there's an example of how to use it.  You will probably need to keep a record of each controls index though so you can set it back to it when it's finished with.

Something like this is probably what you're after:

```
// Get the controls index
int zIndex = parentControl.Controls.GetChildIndex(textBox);
// Bring it to the front
textBox.BringToFront();
// Do something...
// Then send it back again
parentControl.Controls.SetChildIndex(textBox, zIndex);
```

Comment: Everything changes when you dynamically make controls (in)visible. Set 'textbox.Visible = true' and it will have index 0. It complete ignores the order from the document outline. This took me a while to figure :)

Comment: Was trying to figure this out too. This comment helped me out. Thx

Answer (score 1):

When used with the FlowLayoutPanel this will move a control up or down

```
    /// <summary>
    /// When used with the FlowLayoutPanel this will move a control up or down
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="UpDown"></param>
    private void C_On_Move(object sender, int UpDown)
    {
        //If UpDown = 1 Move UP, If UpDown = 0 Move DOWN
        Control c = (Control)sender;
        // Get the controls index
        int zIndex = _flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(c);
        if (UpDown==1 && zIndex > 0)
        {
            // Move up one
            _flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(c, zIndex - 1);
        }
        if (UpDown == 0 && zIndex < _flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count-1)
        {
            // Move down one
            _flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(c, zIndex + 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In C Sharp

**Control.SetValue(Panel.ZIndexProperty,0);**

Control is your control.
0 is index of ZIndex.
0 is default value.

Comment: Looks like WPF, not WinForms

Comment: Make sure to use code formatting!