# c# custom Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom panel containing some buttons and labels. The problem is that I can't set displaying order properly in code. I have something like this:

```
 public partial class Pallete1 : Panel
    {
        private Label lblAutomatic;       
        private Label lbldivider1;

        public Pallete1():base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.lblAutomatic = new Label();
            this.lbldivider1 = new Label();

            this.lblAutomatic.Size = new Size(182,21);
            this.lblAutomatic.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.lblAutomatic.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 64);
            this.lblAutomatic.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.lblAutomatic.Text = "Automatycznie";
            this.lblAutomatic.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8);

            this.lbldivider1.Size = new Size(2,22);
            this.lbldivider1.Location = new Point(26, 0);
            this.lbldivider1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.lbldivider1.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            this.lbldivider1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;


            this.Size = new Size(182, 184);
            this.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{this.lblAutomatic,this.lbldivider1});

        }
```

I would like `lbldivider1` to be **on the top of** `lblAutomatic`. When I add this item to some `WinForm` projects, this second label is only seen when I drag my custom panel from one place to another. However it's not seen in the designer when it's not moving and also when I'm launching the application.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What about adding a `this.lbldivider1.BringToFront()` ?

Comment: I've tried this one already, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What doesn't work for you? I've tried your posted code and it does work (I see a vertical line)

Comment: Well, I don't see it in my project..

Comment: What's so special in your project? I've opened a new WinForms project, pasted your code, added what @TaW said at the end of your method above, buiid, drop on a form - and it's there, in both design and run time

Comment: Well, I did the same and I can't see the vertical line. As I've said, I see it only while dragging the control in designer.

Comment: Good luck then. In order to get help, you must provide a code that we can run and duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you don't have some hidden code, any of the following should work:

(A)

```
this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{this.lblAutomatic,this.lbldivider1});
this.lbldivider1.BringToFront();
```

(B)

```
this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{this.lblAutomatic,this.lbldivider1});
this.lblAutomatic.SendToBack();
```

(C) Simply swap when adding (make sure `lbldivider1` goes first in z order)

```
this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{this.lbldivider1, this.lblAutomatic});
```

Comment: thanks! I appreciate this feedback a lot. Of course I was doing a stupid thing, I mean I've added `this.lbldivider1.BringToFront()` before adding it to panel's list of controls. Really thanks, sometimes such stupid mistakes steal lot of time:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set label's position over second one, use ZOrder property, in case of putting one under another, you would choose TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: Maybe add some examples to show the OP how to do this? Without writing the code for them of course.

Comment: I don't know `Windows.Forms.Control` having a property called `ZOrder`

Comment: Indeed, there's no `ZOrder` property.

Comment: No such property `ZOrder` in WinForms https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213270/how-to-set-z-order-of-a-control-using-winforms) it seems ZOrder is a VB property not available in C#, however there is a `SetChildIndex` on the parent's `Controls` collection.

Try

```
this.Controls.SetChildIndex(lblAutomatic, 1);
this.Controls.SetChildIndex(lbldivider1, 2);
```