# Adding every new button on top of the old button dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I would like my every new button that is created dynamically to be on top of the old button at a particular location. What should I do ? Bring To Front doesn't help me in getting to it. Below is my Code

```
    int l=0;
    public void CreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button exitButton1 = new Button();
        l++;
        exitButton1.Text = "X("+l+")";
        exitButton1.Top = 500;
        exitButton1.Left = 10;
        exitButton1.Width = 50;
        exitButton1.Height = 30;

        exitButton1.Click += (_, args) =>
        {
            exitButton1.Hide();
        };

        this.Controls.Add(exitButton1);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know; but doing this in general is really, really weird. There should only be one button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Z-order of a Control using WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213270/how-to-set-z-order-of-a-control-using-winforms)

Comment: Where were you calling `.BringToFront()`? When I add `exitButton1.BringToFront();` after the code you showed it works fine.

Comment: I added it just below exitButton1 . Height

Comment: Put it as the last line of this code underneath `this.Controls.Add(exitButton1);`

Comment: Thank you Sir, it really helped me.

Comment: If all buttons appear at the same location, and hence only one can be visible at any given point in time, why don't you just use the same button all the time, and just change the `.Text` property of it?

Comment: Well that's really a very good idea Sir, I really like that. As because I am new to C#, I thought of using this as as Undo Button(so I wanted all my buttons on the same location), so that it would be easier for me to undo all my tasks one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply with `List<button>` you can do it:

```
    int l=0;
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button exitButton1 = new Button();
        l++;
        exitButton1.Text = "X(" + l + ")";
        exitButton1.Top = 10;
        exitButton1.Left = 10;
        exitButton1.Width = 50;
        exitButton1.Height = 30;

        exitButton1.Click += (_, args) =>
        {
            exitButton1.Hide();
            buttons.Remove(exitButton1);

            if (buttons.Count() != 0)
            {
                buttons[buttons.Count - 1].Show();
            }
        };

        if (buttons.Count() != 0)
        {
            buttons[buttons.Count - 1].Hide();
        }

        buttons.Add(exitButton1);
        this.Controls.Add(exitButton1);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir !!