# How to drag and drop images in windows froms and get the order

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, containers

I have this problem.
I have multiple images that I want to display inside a container, then the user can reorder them using "drag and drop" inside the container.
After that I have to "understand" the new order and retrive some informations, like the tag, in the new order.

I have tried using listView and imageList but the problem is that if I have images with different sizes they aren't handled in the right way, because you can set just a size (with and height) for all of the images in the imageList.

Is there any other container, or othere strategies, that are more flexible?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just add images as pictureboxes in a regular panel? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213270/how-to-set-z-order-of-a-control-using-winforms

Comment: Yes, this calls for pictureboxes, maybe in a flowlayout panel or in a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this solution! Thanks!

Comment: Note: PictueBox can Zoom in/out to display the images in any size. TLP will have fixed row- and column-sizes while FLP will try to fit conrols of any sizes into its area

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in leveraging a commercial product, the LEADTOOL SDK has components which contain this functionality (note I work for this vendor).  The ImageViewer component have interactive modes which can be extended for drag-and-drop reordering functionality.
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/c/imageviewerinteractivemode.html

There's a demo available on the site which already showcases what you're looking for:
https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DragDrop/

A .NET example is also available.
https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12446-HOW-TO--Rearrange-pages-in-the-LEADTOOLS-Virtual-Document